# Iterating over UITableViewCell for AVSpeechSynthesizer

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, avspeechsynthesizer

I've seen everywhere that it's bad practice to iterate through a tableView but I'm afraid I have no other alternative. I want to have the AVSpeechSynthesizer read the content of the labels that are inside my custom UITableViewCells.
Of course, this could be done directly using the source array of the tableView but the problem is that I want to have the synthesiser read the labels and at the same time highlight the words that are being spoken.
I have done some tests but the problem is that as the cells are being reused by the table view, I end up with empty cells...

What is the right way of ensuring my cells are not empty ? 
I've tried scrolling the tableView to ensure the cells aren't empty but it doesn't work either.

Here is my code so far ...

```
 func scrollToRow(rowToGo: Int) {

    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: self.indexPath as IndexPath, at: .centeredVertically, animated: true)
    let colorCell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ColorCell", for:indexPath as IndexPath ) as! ColorCell
    let myString = colorCell.colorLabel.text!
    print(myString)
    self.speakString(sender: self, str:(myString))

}

   @IBAction func playPauseButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if !self.speechSynthesizer.isSpeaking{
        let btnImage = UIImage(named: "pausedButton.png")
        self.playPauseButton.setImage(btnImage , for: UIControlState.normal)

        self.isPaused = false
       // var indexPath:Double = 0
        self.indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        for i in 0...36 {
            print(i)
         self.indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: i, section:0)
          self.scrollToRow(rowToGo:i)
           // self.indexPath = NSIndexPath(index:i)
           // self.collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredVertically)

        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt
        indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell { 
        let myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:  
        "ColorCell", for: indexPath) as! ColorCell 
        myCell.colorLabel.text = self.wordList[indexPath.row] 
        myCell.colorImage.image = self.images[indexPath.row] 
        return myCell }
```

My collectionView is displayed correctly and all my labels inside the UICollectionViewCells contain text. However, when I press the play button, the first time, nothing gets spoken. If I scroll back and press again, only 3 or 4 cells actually exist and get their label.text printed and spoken while all the other indexes are empty. 
 Any suggestion would be welcome

Comment: how are you end up with empty cells? after scrolling you don't have any text?

Comment: so you need to make some debugging, what is in your `cellForRow` that is breaking cells

Comment: and when you scroll it back text appears?

Comment: @Lu_The text always appears in my tableView. It's just the function that is supposed to read the cells that can't find it each time